# Splitting a string which contain multiple symbols to get specific values

Tags: c#, split

I cannot believe I am having trouble with this following string

```
String filter = "name=Default;pattern=%%;start=Last;end=Now";
```

This is a short and possibly duplicate question, but how would I split this string to get:

```
string Name = "Default";
string Pattern = "%%" ;
string start = "Last" ;
string end = "Now" ;
```

Reason why I ask is my deadline is very soon, and this is literally the last thing I must do. I'm Panicking, and I'm stuck on this basic command. I tried:

```
pattern = filter.Split(new string[] { "pattern=", ";" },
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]; //Gets the pattern
startDate = filter.Split(new string[] { "start=", ";" },
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]; //Gets the start date
```

I happen to get the pattern which I needed, but as soon as I try to split start, I get the value as "Pattern=%%"

What can I do?

**Forgot to mention**
The list in this string which needs splitting may not be in any particular order . this is a single sample of a string which will be read out of a stringCollection (reading these filters from Properties.Settings.Filters

Comment: I think SO heard your call *I'm Panicking* :)

Comment: so many answers have `'` for `"`. This is c sharp guys, not javascript. Ex `'='` is wrong.

Comment: @Kaf [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) takes a char, by means of a `params char[]` overload.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Oh really? I never knew that. Every little helps... + 1

Comment: sorry for delay to answer, testing best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start date ends up at the thrird position in the array:

```
startDate = filter.Split(new string[] { "start=", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2];
```

Instead of splitting the string once for each value, you might want to split it into the separate key-value pairs, then split each pair:

```
string[] pairs = filter.Split(';');
string[] values = pairs.Select(pair => pair.Split('=')[1]).ToArray();

string name = values[0];
string pattern = values[1];
string start = values[2];
string end = values[3];
```

(This code of course assumes that the key-value pairs always come in the same order.)

You could also split the string into intersperced array, so that every other item is a key or a value:

```
string[] values = filter.Split(new string[] { "=", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

string name = values[1];
string pattern = values[3];
string start = values[5];
string end = values[7];
```

#### Edit:

To handle key-values in any order, make a lookup from the string, and pick values from it:

```
ILookup<string, string> values =
  filter.Split(';')
  .Select(s => s.Split('='))
  .ToLookup(p => p[0], p => p[1]);

string name = values["name"].Single();
string pattern = values["pattern"].Single();
string start = values["start"].Single();
string end = values["end"].Single();
```

You can use `SingleOrDefault` if you want to support values being missing from the string:

```
string name = values["name"].SingleOrDefault() ?? "DefaultName";
```

The lookup also supports duplicate key-value pairs. If there might be duplicates, just loop through the values:

```
foreach (var string name in values["name"]) {
  // do something with the name
}
```

Comment: Wont always be in this specific order

Comment: @EonRustedduPlessis: I see. I added a solution for that too.

Comment: checking it out. give me a sec

Comment: because @Andy Holt used .ToDictionary with a similar method, and I had indexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Compiler error, cannot implicitly convert the type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'

Comment: desperate for the answer tick :P ?

Answer (score 3):

Using `string.Split` this is a two stage process.

In the first case split on `;` to get an array of keyword and value pairs:

```
string[] values = filter.Split(';');
```

Then loop over the resultant list splitting on `=` to get the keywords and values:

```
foreach (string value in values)
{
    string[] pair = value.Split('=');
    string key = pair[0];
    string val = pair[1];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea! This does not cater for unspecific ordering of the filter variable, but it works to Split the filter by ;, then iterating through it when splitting it by the =, checking each result if it resembles the info that we want (by string.StartsWith())

Answer (score 2):

```
String filter = "name=Default;pattern=%%;start=Last;end=Now";
string[] temp = filter.Split('=');
string name = temp[1].Split(';')[0];
string pattern = temp[2].Split(';')[0];
string start = temp[3].Split(';')[0];
string end = temp[4].Split(';')[0];
```

Comment: This would actually work, but does the splits in a strange way.

Comment: this works, yes, I took all the answers and glued a simple solution together

Comment: one that can cater for when the order of the string changes, and if invalid values are found , i can fall back on hard-coded default values (already inserted at later code)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
string filter = "name=Default;pattern=%%;start=Last;end=Now";

// Make a dictionary.
var lookup = filter
   .Split(';')
   .Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Split('='))
   .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);

// Get values out of the dictionary.
string name = lookup["name"];
string pattern = lookup["pattern"];
string start = lookup["start"];
string end = lookup["end"];
```

Comment: As good as this one seems , i somehow get "Index out of bounds of array". must be an id10t error on my side, checking in to it further.

Answer (score 1):

You see, the thing is now that your `Split` on `filter` a second time still *starts from the beginning of the string*, and it matches against `;`, so since the string hasn't changed, you still retrieve previous matches (so your index accessor is off by *X*).

You could break this down into it's problem parts, such that:

```
var keyValues = filter.Split(';');
var name = keyValues[0].Split('=')[1];
var pattern = keyValues[1].Split('=')[1];
var start = keyValues[2].Split('=')[1];
var end = keyValues[3].Split('=')[1];
```

Note that the above code is potentially prone to error, and as such should be properly altered.

Comment: you gave me the idea to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried something like this:

```
 var result = "name=Default;pattern=%%;start=Last;end=Now".Split(new char[]{'=',';'});

  for(int i=0;i<result.Length; i++)
  {          
      if(i%2 == 0) continue;
      Console.WriteLine(result[i]);
  }
```

and the output is:

```
Default
%%
Last
Now
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
 String filter = "name=Default;pattern=%%;start=Last;end=Now";
 string[] parts = filter.Split(';');

 string Name = parts[0].Substring(parts[0].IndexOf('=') + 1);
 string Pattern = parts[1].Substring(parts[1].IndexOf('=') + 1);
 string start = parts[2].Substring(parts[2].IndexOf('=') + 1);
 string end = parts[3].Substring(parts[3].IndexOf('=') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String filter = "name=Default;pattern=%%;start=Last;end=Now";
var parts = filter.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split('='))
                             .Where(x => x.Length == 2)
                             .Select(x => new {key = x[0], value=x[1]});
string name = "";
string pattern = "";
string start = "";
string end = "";
foreach(var part in parts)
{
    switch(part.key)
    {
        case "name":
            name = part.value;
            break;
        case "pattern":
            pattern = part.value;
            break;
        case "start":
            start = part.value;
            break;
        case "end":
            end = part.value;
            break;
    }
}
```

If you don't need the values in named variables, you only need the second line. It returns an enumerable with key/value pairs.

My solution has the added benefits that the order of those key/value pairs in the string is irrelevant and it silently ignores invalid parts instead of crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution on my own too. Most of your answers would have worked if the list would have been in the same order every single time, but it wont be. the format however, will always stay the same. The solution is a simple iteration using a `foreach` loop, and then checking if it starts with a certain word, namely, the word I am looking for, like Name, Pattern etc.

Probably not the most cpu efficient way of doing it, but it is C# for dummies level. Really brain-fade level.

Here is my beauty.

```
                foreach (string subfilter in filter.Split(';')) //filter.Split is a string [] which can be iterated through
                {
                    if (subfilter.ToUpper().StartsWith("PATTERN"))
                    {
                        pattern = subfilter.Split('=')[1];
                    }
                    if (subfilter.ToUpper().StartsWith("START"))
                    {
                        startDate = subfilter.Split('=')[1];
                    }
                    if (subfilter.ToUpper().StartsWith("END"))
                    {
                        endDate = subfilter.Split('=')[1];
                    }
                }
```

Comment: just, startDate and endDate are both just string variables. nothing big.

Comment: This app will run on a 3Ghz 8 cores machine with 16 GB ram. so , this wont touch performance much anyway.